# How can I look to screen pixel faster?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swiftui

I am trying to make an app like apple made called **Digital Color Meter**:

[image]

if you look to this app it has a view in left showing small part of screen in pixels, my goal is building this part first and then working in other parts. Also because I wanted codes be clean and less code as well I used SwiftUI-macOS but this not a fixed thing I can code in Cocoa-macos as well or you can answer in each way you like or solve the issue.

Speaking of issue, the issue is that my code does done the job but it takes lots of time for finishing and it acts like loading a 4k video game! In the other hand the apple software **Digital Color Meter** do this work in less than a sec and so fast.

The other issue is that my mac alerts me that my app trying record screen and it is another facepalm!

The other issue is from Xcode complains for:

> [default] 0 is not a valid connection ID

Here the screenshot of app:

[image]

[image]

Here is my codes, looking to make this app works faster, if I am approaching to read the screen pixel or lets say trying read the image of screen in wrong way please hit me with the correct way, finding the correct way and fast is the goal not debagging this app, but you are free to debag as your wish:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var myArray: [[PixelInfoType]] = [[PixelInfoType]]()
    
    private let rectOrigin: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 500.0, y: 500.0)
    private let spacing: CGFloat = 2.0
    private let pixelSize: CGFloat = 5.0
    private let imageSize: Int = 50
    
    @State private var buildIsDone: Bool = false
    @State private var fillIsDone: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Color.gray
            
            VStack {
                
                if (buildIsDone && fillIsDone) {
                    
                    VStack(spacing: spacing) {
                        
                        ForEach(myArray, id:\.self) { outsideElement in
                            
                            HStack(spacing: spacing) {
                                
                                ForEach(outsideElement, id:\.id) { element in
                                    
                                    colorProcesor(nsColor: element.nsColor).frame(width: pixelSize, height: pixelSize)
                                    
                                }
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }

                
                Button("build matrix") {
                    
                    buildIsDone = false
                    myArray.removeAll()
                    
                    Array(0...imageSize).forEach { yElement in
                        
                        var lineArray: [PixelInfoType] = [PixelInfoType]()
                        
                        Array(0...imageSize).forEach { xElement in
                            lineArray.append(PixelInfoType(point: CGPoint(x: rectOrigin.x + CGFloat(xElement), y: rectOrigin.y + CGFloat(yElement))))
                        }
                        
                        myArray.append(lineArray)
                        
                    }
                    
                    buildIsDone = true
                    
                }
                
                if (buildIsDone) {
                    
                    Button("fill matrix with color") {
                        
                        fillIsDone = false
                        
                        myArray.indices.forEach { outsideIndex in
                            
                            myArray[outsideIndex].indices.forEach { index in
                                
                                myArray[outsideIndex][index].nsColor = pixelColorReader(point: myArray[outsideIndex][index].point)
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                        fillIsDone = true
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}

func colorProcesor(nsColor: NSColor? = nil) -> Color {
    
    if let unwrappedNSColor: NSColor = nsColor { return Color(nsColor: unwrappedNSColor) }
    else { return .green }
    
}

struct PixelInfoType: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var point: CGPoint
    var nsColor: NSColor?
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}


func pixelColorReader(point: CGPoint) -> NSColor? {
    
    let screenID = NSScreen.main!.deviceDescription[NSDeviceDescriptionKey("NSScreenNumber")] as! UInt32
    let image: CGImage = CGDisplayCreateImage(CGDirectDisplayID(screenID), rect: CGRect(x: point.x, y: point.y, width: 1, height: 1))!
    let bitmap = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: image)
    let color = bitmap.colorAt(x: 0, y: 0)
    
    return color
    
}
```

Comment: You are calling CGDisplayCreateImage for every pixel. The first of many optimizations would be to call that once.

Comment: It does  make sense, thanks! I have to think about coding it how should I read the needed pixels info with just one call to CGDisplayCreateImage.

Comment: Hint: you are in a forEach. Do the screenshot outside of that forEach.

Comment: @jnpdx: I tried to convert `NSBitmapImageRep` image to `CGImage` and then I convert it to `NSImage` and then that to `Image`, it means in 3 steps, am I in right track? also I am still getting the Xcode complain about `[default] 0 is not a valid connection ID.`

Comment: @jnpdx: "you are in a forEach" you mean the action of `fill matrix with color` or ForEach of SwiftUI?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60854494/default-0-is-not-a-valid-connection-id-error-with-swift-and-cocoa-programmatica

Comment: @jnpdx: thanks, I looked to that link, that issue was about window but i have no window issue, as soon as i call pixelColorReader function that complain happens, I am like 100% sure it is because of that function not window, you can try to call the function and that complain also happens.